# How effective was the Geass Canceler?

Tags: code-geass

The Geass Canceller of Jeremiah Gotwald cancels the effects of Geass on people who have been affected.

His Geass Canceller is effective on the people that Lelouch, Rolo, and Charles have cast their Geass on.

But how about with the Geass of Marian, the Knight Of One, and Mao?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is no direct evidence to explain how it would affect them I would assume,

- With the Knight of One, Bismark, I would dare say he wouldn't see the "before images" thus unable to predict their movement. Considering that he was the Knight of One and had his eye sewn shut, I would assume it wouldn't hinder him all that much not having his Geass as he would have been able to prove himself to others without his Geass (he position of Knight of One may have been just because he's in league with the Order)
- With Marian, I dare say it would kill her has it was her Geass which kept her alive in Anya. If she was in her own body she wouldn't be able to transfer her conscientiousness so had the Canceller been in use when V.V attacked her she would have died
- With Mao it would be similar to how his Geass Power reacts with those with The Code. Effectiveness depends as Mao became focused on C.C so much because she was the only person he couldn't read the mind of, on the one hand The Order could use it to prevent their secrets being discovered but on the other hand Mao may affiliate himself as a member of the Order because he would be with other people he can't read the minds of, a sense of peace for him

The problem is that the Geass the Canceller dispelled in the series were Geass Powers which didn't benefit the caster directly. with Marian's, Bismark's and Mao's Geass there are sustained effects and they reap all the benefits (ie. Marian can jump bodies, Bismark can just react with foreknowledge and Mao can gain info from other's minds) as such the question needs to be asked how the Canceller would work with them. Would the Area of Effect shown when Jeremiah used it (the blue sphere) apply an "immunity" effect to those in the area or would it only work on who has it equipped.

the one point in the series were we could see wether or not the Canceler applied an immunity effect is when Shirley dies. Lelouch is using his Geass on her but we don't know if it was having any effect on her has his order was to keep her alive when she had been shot and on the verge of death. also if she had immunity to Geass it may have been as a result of her dying, as shown when Euphie was dying and the Geass effects on her was dispelling.

Given that Bismark is in league with The Order there is the chance functionality against his Geass may have been developed as the Canceller worked on the Geass Effects of current members and one person who was their captive (and the children who forced a Knightmare Pilot to shoot his allies during the attack on the Order may have been a by-product of research on Lelouch's Geass given it's similarities).

Comment: A very informative answer! I'm confused if Marian would really die, and how long does this Geass Canceler be sustain if it will be used for The Order.

Comment: @OdracirPapa well with Marianne its only a possibility that she could return to her original body, wether she could return it or not is another thing as we don't know the full limits to Marianne's Geass, particularly if her spirit can not enter a body it once inhabited in a similar manner to how Lelouch can't use his Geass twice on the same person, if that is the case then her spirit becomes disembodied and who knows what will happen to it after that

Comment: (cont.) as for how long the Canceler could sustain itself that is also an unknown. as I have mentioned there is a difference to how Lelouch's, Rolo's and Charles's Geass and that of Marianne's, Bismark's and Mao's. think about Geass like a RPG Status Effect. Lelouch applies a Debuff like Blind or Weakness and the Geass Canceler is like Esuna where it removes the Debuff. Bismark's is like a Buff like a haste or Strength but even if the Canceler acts like Disspell the effect is applied again.

Comment: (cont.) the only way to get around that is if the Canceler disables the Geass User ability to use Geass and to me that should have been  the first thing the Order would have done given Rolo's power but we don't see that. however all of this is just speculation as the Canceler was introduced late in Season 2 so we need a Season 3 to see how it can be used further

Comment: I see? Geass Canceller cancels the effect of the Lelouch Geass right? So Lelouch can cast again his Geass to the same person which he cast his geass and cancelled by the Canceller (i.e Shirley)

Comment: @OdracirPapa that I don't know, Shirley is the only person who we see him try and apply his Geass on again after she was hit with the Canceler but wether it was having an effect or not is unknown. we see no sign that the his order was being applied which could be because the order itself was something impossible to do, because Shirley was dying, because she may still count as having had Geass used on her or she may have been made immune thanks to the Canceler but on the other hand Lelouch's Geass may have worked but because Shirley can't stop death itself then it was just a wasted order

Comment: Concluding with your comments, so it is actually cancelled so therefore it can be cast again. Thanks!